# Optaplanner Logger should also show customer id for each move

Tags: optaplanner

I am using `trace` in `logback.xml`, and have different classes derived from 
`SelectionFilter`.

When the `moves` are `traced` they are related to the `locations IDs` of the
customers. Is it internally possible to use in addition/instead the
`customer IDs`, to find out what happens during the moves?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to **6.3.0.Beta1** or later. The logging has been improved to show the entity's toString(), its old planning value toString() and its new planning value toString().